# Why does this line take so long to run?

Tags: python, performance

I have the following code, which gets a graph and set of ids to exclude, and returns the ids of nodes that do not appear in the nodes to exclude list.

I have two versions of the code. One that gets two lists, and the other that gets one list. I am using `itertools.chain` to combine the two lists.

```
from itertools import chain

def GrapMinusNodes(Graph,nodes_to_exclude1,nodes_to_exclude2):
    return (item.GetId() for item in Graph.Nodes() if item.GetId() not in chain(nodes_to_exclude1,nodes_to_exclude2))
```

and I have this one:

```
def GrapMinusNodes(Graph,nodes_to_exclude1,nodes_to_exclude2):
    return (item.GetId() for item in Graph.Nodes() if item.GetId() not in nodes_to_exclude1)
```

The first method runs 20% slower than the second one.
What is the reason for that?
Is there a way to make this code run faster?

Comment: This is because you create the `chain` for each item in `Graph.Nodes()` in the first method

Comment: Well, you have to create chain object, and creating it has non-zero cost. What exactly are you expecting? More processor instructions processed in same time?

Comment: create the `chain` object outside of the loop :)

Comment: Wow! I was so sure that there will be some kind of automatic fix for these types of errors that I didn't even think it worth to create the object outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `chain` here? Checking membership is `O(n)` for an iterable, and you have to recreate that iterable for each item you're checking. Instead, pre-create a `set` and test membership using that:

```
exclude = set().union(nodes_to_exclude1, nodes_to_exclude2)
return (item.GetId() for item in Graph.Nodes() if item.GetId() not in exclude)
```